# Captured images from front-facing camera are rotated - Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I do basic Windows Phone application. I need capture photos by front facing camera.
Preview is OK, but captured phoho is rotated(90°).

CS:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.FrontFacing) == true)
        {            
            cam = new PhotoCamera(CameraType.FrontFacing);
            cam.CaptureImageAvailable += new EventHandler<Microsoft.Devices.ContentReadyEventArgs>(cam_CaptureImageAvailable);
            viewfinderBrush.SetSource(cam);               
        }
        else
        {
            txtMessage.Text = "No front camera";
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Canvas x:Name="viewfinderCanvas" Height="640" Width="480" Tap="viewfinder_Tapped" Margin="0,138,0,46" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Canvas.Background>
            <VideoBrush x:Name="viewfinderBrush">
                <VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform
                        x:Name="viewfinderTransform"
                        CenterX="0.5"
                        CenterY="0.5"
                        Rotation="-90"/>
                </VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
            </VideoBrush>
        </Canvas.Background>
    </Canvas>
```

Sorry for my English...

Comment: Can you try 90 in the rotation value instead of -90 and also can you specify the     SupportedOrientations value and Orientation value in the basepage tag in the Xaml of the page

Comment: When I set rotation to 90 = display of camera is upside down. In SupportedOrientations i have Portrait...

Comment: can you remove the supportedOrientations as i have mentioned below, thats how I resolved this issue

Comment: I try this, but without success. What do you mean: check. then changing the rotation to 90?

Answer (score 0):

Try Removing the SupportedOrientations and Orientation from the page and check. then changing the rotation to 90